# Format the color of a cell in a pandas dataframe according to multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

I am trying to format the color of a cell of an specific column in a data frame, but I can't manage to do it according to multiple conditions.

This is my dataframe (df):

```
    Name     ID         Cel     Date
0   Diego   b000000005  7878    2565-05-31 20:53:00
1   Luis    b000000015  6464    2017-05-11 20:53:00
2   Vidal   b000000002  1100    2017-05-08 20:53:00
3   John    b000000011  4545    2017-06-06 20:53:00
4   Yusef   b000000013  1717    2017-06-06 20:53:00
```

I want the values in the "Date" column to change color according to the following conditions:

```
 if date < datetime.now():
        color = 'green'
    elif date > datetime.now():
        date = 'yellow'
    elif date > (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=60)):
        color = 'red'
```

This is my current code:

```
def color(val):
    if val < datetime.now():
        color = 'green'
    elif val > datetime.now():
        color = 'yellow'
    elif val > (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=60)):
        color = 'red'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

df.style.apply(color, subset = ['Fecha'])
```

I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index Fecha')

The output is:

```
Out[65]: <pandas.formats.style.Styler at 0x1e3ab8dec50>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: EDIT: the error is: ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index Date')

Comment: It should read:  "df.style.apply(color, subset = ['Date'])"

Missed that translation...

Comment: One of your `Date` entries is in the year `2565`.  The rest are set in `2017`.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. It was for testing purposes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

name = ['Diego', 'Luis', 'Vidal', 'John', 'Yusef']
id = ['b000000005', 'b000000015', 'b000000002', 'b000000011', 'b000000013']
cel = [7878, 6464, 1100, 4545, 1717]
date = pd.to_datetime(['2017-05-31 20:53:00', '2017-05-11 20:53:00', '2017-05-08 20:53:00', 
                       '2017-06-06 20:53:00', '2017-06-06 20:53:00'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':name,'ID':id,'Cel':cel,'Date':date})

def color(val):
    if val < datetime.now():
        color = 'green'
    elif val > datetime.now():
        color = 'yellow'
    elif val > (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=60)):
        color = 'red'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

df.style.applymap(color, subset=['Date'])
```

[image: pandas styler output]

Screenshot from Jupyter notebook.  If you `print` the output instead, you'll just get a reference to the `Styler` object:

```
print(df.style.applymap(color, subset=['Date']))
<pandas.formats.style.Styler object at 0x116db43d0>
```

Comment: Thank you! Great answer. It threw me an error while entering the last elif. I changed every condition to "if" and it worked perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept this answer by clicking the check mark if has solved your problem.

Comment: yes this code working well in jupyter but in spyder it is not working for me.can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

The way it is written, no cells would be painted red.
You should change the order, letting the condition to paint red before the one to paint yellow.