# how to draw a beautiful colorful table with pandas or other package in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to draw a colorful table, like this.

[image]

this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43839318/11074017) provides an approach.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

name = ['Diego', 'Luis', 'Vidal', 'John', 'Yusef']
id = ['b000000005', 'b000000015', 'b000000002', 'b000000011', 'b000000013']
cel = [7878, 6464, 1100, 4545, 1717]
date = pd.to_datetime(['2017-05-31 20:53:00', '2017-05-11 20:53:00', '2017-05-08 20:53:00', 
                       '2017-06-06 20:53:00', '2017-06-06 20:53:00'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':name,'ID':id,'Cel':cel,'Date':date})

def color(val):
    if val < datetime.now():
        color = 'green'
    elif val > datetime.now():
        color = 'yellow'
    elif val > (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=60)):
        color = 'red'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

df.style.applymap(color, subset=['Date'])
```

exactly same code from that post, produces a different output.

[image]

the borders are missing, the color is also different from the one in the post.

what am i missing?

Comment: Maybe using something like [this](https://bixense.com/clicolors/) might be useful?

Answer (score 2):

First use pandas `style` for set background colors with custom function and then [`Styler.set_table_styles`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_table_styles.html) for set `css` styles:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Red':[1,1,0,0,0],'Yellow':[0,0,1,0,1],'Green':[0,0,0,1,0]})
print (df)

def color(x): 
   c1 = 'background-color: green'
   c2 = 'background-color: yellow'
   c3 = 'background-color: red'
   c4 = '' 
   m = x == 1
   print (m)

   df1 = pd.DataFrame(c4, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
   df1.loc[m['Red'], 'Red'] = c1
   df1.loc[m['Yellow'], 'Yellow'] = c2
   df1.loc[m['Green'], 'Green'] = c3
   return df1
```

---

```
df.style.apply(color,axis=None).set_table_styles(
   [{
       'selector': 'th',
       'props': [
           ('background-color', 'blue'),
           ('color', 'white'),
           ('border-color', 'black'),
           ('border-style ', 'solid'),
           ('border-width','1px')]
   },
    {
       'selector': 'td',
       'props': [
           ('border-color', 'black'),
           ('border-style ', 'solid'),
           ('border-width','1px')]
   },
    {'selector': '.row_heading',
          'props': [('display', 'none')]},
    {'selector': '.blank.level0',
          'props': [('display', 'none')]}])
```

---

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0):

1. `datetime.now()` is different from the linked post (May2017) and your post (May2019), hence the difference in color.
2. You don't see the lines because your jupyter theme default's different. The code only colors the target cells. Here's the output of the same code on my computer:

[image]

Comment: which jupyter theme should I choose?

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48798508/jupyter-pandas-dataframe-output-table-format-configuration).